# Spork + Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spork, minitest

Can anyone explain how to use Spork with Minitest. I see there's a [spork-minitest gem](https://github.com/semaperepelitsa/spork-minitest), but it's not clear how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after you add it to your Gemfile, you can use the docs at https://github.com/sporkrb/spork and substitute in 'minitest'.

so you can do `spork minitest --bootstrap`

then to run tests, spork-minitest provides a `testdrb` which you can pass tests into so `testdrb test/unit/something_test.rb`

Comment: Worked great, thanks. Only other thing I had to do was add /vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.2/bin to my PATH.